# auto create statistics

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just can't get around my head about AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS? I run the tuning advisor and it advised me to create statistics on a table. the AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS is set to true and i would have expected the statistics would have been created automatically. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS option does not determine whether statistics get created for indexes. This option also does not generate filtered statistics. It applies strictly to **single-column statistics** for the full table."

From here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx

But I must say, like so many other important parts of documentation, that was buried.

Comment: in what circumstance the AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS will create the statistic then?

Comment: AFAIK, only when it sees a stat for a single column it can add. In my experience, usually if I'm worrying about anything past just indexing, the stats aren't going to be single column. I am sure others will have different opinions on that though. I have never relied on it at all, so had to go look up even that much. I've been taught by some guys that really knew what they were doing to make sure that I'm paying attention to my own stats.